# What is nuclear norm of a tensor?

Tags: pytorch

When I do

```
import torch
x = torch.ones(3, 4)
x.norm(p='nuc')
```

it gives

```
tensor(3.4641)
```

how is this value calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nuclear norm, aka the trace norm, is the sum of **singular values** of `x` or equivalently one of the expressions below (assuming x is real)

```
u,s,v = torch.svd(x, compute_uv=False)
print(torch.sum(s))
```

---

```
eigs, eigvecs = torch.symeig(x.transpose(1,0) @ x)
print(torch.sum(torch.sqrt(torch.abs(eigs))))
```

---

Finding the matrix square root isn't supported natively in pytorch (you could use `symeig` but then this would reduce to the previous expression). If you use something like [this `sqrtm` implementation](https://github.com/steveli/pytorch-sqrtm/blob/master/sqrtm.py) then you can compute the nuclear norm using

```
print(torch.trace(sqrtm(x.transpose(1,0) @ x))
```

From the above expression, it should be clear that if `x` is positive semi-definite then the trace norm is just

```
# use this only if you know x is positive semi-definite
print(torch.trace(x))
```

Comment: I think second formula is for frobenius norm

Comment: The frobenius norm is just `torch.sqrt(torch.sum(x**2))`. It's basically the L2-Norm if you "unroll" the matrix into a vector shape. But you're right that I have a typo in the trace norm. Let me rewrite it.

Comment: I don't think your last statement is true. x needs to be positive semi-definite for that to be true.

Comment: @JackShi Certainly! Thanks for pointing out that mistake.